# Where is platform.h?

Tags: ros, headers, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a publisher in c++ and I must include platform.h, but I cannot find it in any directory, and include the directory.Where is platform.h?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12594/where-is-platform.h?/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does a lot of magic behind the scenes in the build system that makes searching for headers like this unnecessary.

Instead, you should add the proper dependency to your manifest, which will automatically set up the proper include and library compile flags.

In this case, I'm guessing that you need to add a dependency on roscpp.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1